# Safari, timer slowed down

Tags: javascript, macos, web-applications, safari

I'm doing js timer for web application.

Here is my code

```
 var timerVar = setInterval(countTimer, 1000);

        var totalSeconds = 0;

        function countTimer() {
            ++totalSeconds;
            var hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour * 3600) / 60);
            var seconds = totalSeconds - (hour * 3600 + minutes * 60);
            //document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }

        function myStartTimer() {
            setInterval(countTimer, 1000);
        }

        function myStopTimer() {
            clearInterval(timerVar);
        }
```

on Windows and google chrome everything works correct but problem is with safari webbrowser and OSX system.

I need this timer to be opened in few web browser tabs.
When I change safari web browser tabs the timer slowed down. Only on active tab the time is counted correctly. On other tabs timer has a lag. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: timers are not accurate so you should not be using it for timers. You should use a timestamp and subtract that time from current time.

Comment: You can try to use Page visibility API, when the page is hide you set a Date object, when the page is visible you calculate the hide duration and set your timer value.